# Generated recursive object based on array

Tags: javascript

I have an array, which is a list of keys: `['one', 'two', 'three']`.

I need to generate an object, of the following format:

```
{
  path: 'one',
  nested: {
    path: 'two',
    nested: {
      path: 'three'
    }
  }
}
```

So far I've tried a couple of approaches, but they seem quite messy (I have one method which uses `while(current = array.pop())` but it requires several conditionals to handle the first and last elements.

Is there a neater recursive strategy?

Comment: @Barmar I haven't found any answer that solves the problem recursively in both places, and I have purely recursive solution to share, please reopen this questionç

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Because OP asks so

Comment: What is the expected result when the array is empty? Yes, your current structure does indeed require special handling of the last element, it would be better if it had something like `nested: null`.

Comment: @Bergi we would just add extra condition that checks for that and returns immediately empty object https://jsfiddle.net/6rpg5jc1/

Comment: @BakhtiiarMuzakparov I'm suggesting *not* to return an empty object for that case. Exactly to avoid extra conditions.

Comment: @Bergi so how would you modify it then?

Comment: @BakhtiiarMuzakparov I would return `null` or `undefined` - or maybe even a special object - that would also be the `nested` value of the last path segment.

Comment: @Bergi you are very welcome to change it

Comment: @BakhtiiarMuzakparov No I'm not. I was asking the OP whether it is ok or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method and as accumulator pass object that you want add properties to.

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']
var obj = {}

arr.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  r.path = e;
  return arr[i+1] ? r.nested = {} : r
}, obj)

console.log(obj)
```

If you want to use just recursion without loop you can create function like this.

```js
var data = ['one', 'two', 'three']
var obj = {}

function makeObj(arr, n, o) {
  if (n == arr.length - 1) o.path = arr[n]
  else {
    o.path = arr[n];
    o.nested = {}
    makeObj(arr, n += 1, o.nested)
  }
  return o.nested
}

makeObj(data, 0, obj)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Mutating the accumulator is absolutely ugly. Why not just use `reduceRight` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var tree = arr.reduceRight((nested, path) => {
  return nested? {path, nested}: {path};
}, null);

console.log(tree);
```

or even better/simpler, just:

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var tree = arr.reduceRight((nested, path) => ({path, nested}), null);

console.log(tree);
```

It simplifies things for the JS engine if all objects have the same hidden class *(simplified: same property names)*.

Comment: `reduceRight` is the only correct appraoch here. +1!

Comment: The engine optimisation isn't really relevant. It mostly simplifies things in the code and for the programmer!

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'], obj = {};

obj['path'] = arr[arr.length - 1];
for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
  obj = {
    path: arr[i],
    nested: obj
  };
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: it doesn't look recursive to me

Comment: Recursive solution will fail if array will contain too many elements. But if author needs only recursive solution, so be it ;)

Comment: How will a recursive solution fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decrementing `for` loop to solve this problem:

```js
var props = ['one','two','three'],
    obj;
    
for(var a = props.length;a--;) {
    var temp = { path: props[a] };
    if(obj) {
        temp.nested = obj;
    }
    obj = temp;
}

console.log(obj);
```